# Espresso NoMatchingViewException when using withId matcher

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to write a simple test where I simply click on a MenuItem that is in the main activity:

```
public class doTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<doActivity> {

  public doTest() {
    super(doActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    startActivity();

  }

  private void startActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setActivityIntent(intent);
    getActivity();
  }

  public void testOne() {
    Espresso.openContextualActionModeOverflowMenu();
    onView(withId(R.id.create_new)).perform(ViewActions.click());
  }

}
```

The test fails with "NoMatchingViewException". If I change the onView line to:

```
    onView(withText("Add new")).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

Here is the menu xml for the activity:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/create_new"
        android:title="Add new"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    </item>
```

The test works. Why would the matcher withText find the view whereas the matcher withId not find?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is how it works in Espresso. The problem here is, that in Android, the View representing the menu item doesn't have the ID of the menu item. So `onView(withId(X))` just fails to find a View. I don't have a better recommendation than just using `withText()`. If you have multiple views with the same text, using hierarchy for distinction works.

Comment: Could you please check on the below question, Could you please on this, Thanks in Advance.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472775/navigation-view-android-kotlin-with-espresso-androidx-test-espresso-nomatching

Answer (score 3):

haffax's answer is right. The menu item and the View generated for the menu have different IDs. Using `withText` is the best known practice in this case.

To avoid hardcoding a text like 'Add new' in your test, I would recommmand using a String reference. E.g.,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/create_new"
    android:title="@string/action_create_new"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
/>
```