# Clicking on a menu item in action bar with Espresso when using onView(withId(...))

Tags: android, optionmenu, android-espresso, action-menu

I am making a test using Espresso, first I open the action bar:

```
openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
```

Everything ok up to here, but then I want to click on an option menu:

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_menu)).perform(click());
```

The menu layout xml has an option with id: "action_menu".

I get an error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: ***.********.******.android.debug:id/action_menu
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView{43fd3f58 VFED.VC. .F...... 24,24-612,168}
```

I got this step to work by using:

```
onView(withText(R.string.action_report)).perform(click());
```

I would like to know what is going wrong with the id though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the item really have id="@+id/action_menu"? It sounds from the withText matcher that it could be more specific, like report_action.

Comment: Hi siger, yes the item does have the id `android:id="@+id/action_menu"` but espresso is only finding by text. Still don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the view representing the menu does not know the id, but only the text of an item.
I am new to Espresso and therefore cannot give more details, but this post is related to your problem : 
[Espresso NoMatchingViewException when using withId matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738028/espresso-nomatchingviewexception-when-using-withid-matcher/24743493#24743493)

Comment: Thanks @Coralie B I hadn't been able to find that post before.